# malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5fbff350: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, malloc

I have seen many pages for this error, but I'm not able to grasp what I'm doing wrong with my code, so I was hoping if I posted it, someone could shed some light.

This is a c++ class project. The goal is to write a function that takes two C strings (char*) and returns them concatenated together in a new. What I have here compiles, except for when I try to delete copycat, I get the malloc error in the title of this question.

How can I delete copycat?

I think I should be also deleting the "unused" news I created in the cat2 function (p, q), but that gives me the same error. What am I missing here with deallocating memory?

```
char* cat2(char* dest1, char* str2)
{
    char* p = new char[100];
    char* q = new char[100];
    char* rvalue = new char[100];

    for (p = dest1; *p != 0; p++)
    {
        ;
    }


    for (q = str2; *q != 0; p++, q++ )
    {
        *p = *q;
    }

    *p = 0; /* set the last character to 0 */

    rvalue = dest1;

    return rvalue;
}

void main()
{
    char s1[] = "Hello";
    char s2[] = ", World!";

    char* copycat = cat2(s1, s2);
    cout << copycat; 

    delete copycat;
}
```

Comment: `This is a c++ class project.`  Looks like mostly `C` and very little `C++`.

Comment: Yikes, memory leak central, and all those pointers, and `delete` instead of `delete[]`! Are you _really_ being taught to write C++ in this manner?

Comment: It's true! I'm in the into class and it's mostly presented as if everyone is familiar with C (which I'm not). The other part of this project is to use vectors to do the same thing, which from how it's described seems much simpler than what I have here.

Comment: Nobody should write code like this any more. This leaks memory and will break if the strings are more than 99 characters. If this is what your teacher expects you to do, find a new teacher. In any case, the problem is this line: `rvalue = dest1` You therefore try to delete what comes from `s2` in main. If you made your parameters as follows: `(const char* dest1, const char* str2)` the bad code would not have compiled.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit. I think you're saying to use delete[] instead of delete? But that gives the same error.

Comment: When you fix your other errors, `delete[]` is indeed the correct one to use. With three `new`s in your program as so, your final program should have three `delete[]` statements. There's no need for p or q however to concatenate the strings. In fact, the memory you allocate for `p` is immediately lost in the for loop.

Comment: `It's true! I'm in the into class and it's mostly presented as if everyone is familiar with C`  Learning `C` should not be a prerequisite to learning C++.  IMO a better approach would have the teacher showing you the C code for this problem and then showing the C++ equivalent.  Then go on from there.  This exercise is (again IMO) a waste of your time *if* the goal is to teach vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rvalue = dest1;` makes `rvalue` point to what `dest1` is pointing to. This is the local buffer `s1` inside main.

So calling `delete copycat;` is the same as trying `delete s1;` which fails because it was not allocated via `new`. (and because it should be `delete[]`).

You make the same mistake with `p = dest1;` and `q = str2;`.  These make `p` and `q` point to those buffers. You leaked all the memory you allocated via `new`, and caused a buffer overflow by writing characters past the end of `s1`.

I guess you intended to copy characters into the buffers you allocated via `new`. However, `p` and `q` buffers are useless anyway; you should be copying characters into the buffer pointed to by `rvalue`. To do that you will have to work with `*rvalue` and so on (which means: the location being pointed to by `rvalue`, instead of making `rvalue` point somewhere totally different and leaking memory).

Comment: Thank you Matt. It looks like I'm in the weeds on this one.